# Loading huge Threejs scene using ColladaLoader

Tags: xml, google-chrome, three.js, collada

I need to load huge 3D scene (around 100 MB) into Three.js renderer using Collada loader. 
So far Chrome always fails. I know that it could be an issue with memory management.

Do you have any experiences with loading huge files into the Chrome?

Comment: FWIW I haven't had any problems loading 10MB Collada files, but even that's too big. I'm planning to use [collada2json](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/collada2json) to get rid of the xml overhead, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: I looks like that loading of the file is not a problem, but parsing XML to DOM is.